# TMemoryStream of a file with a string attached to it

Tags: delphi

i have a TMemoryStream of a picture but i want to add a String inside that TMemoryStream that defines what that picture is then read them separately.

the TMemoryStream will be sent from IdTCPclient to IdTCPserver and server will read the string then the picture.
id prefer if the string was in the beginning of the stream.
it is my first encounter on dealing with memory stream with multiple date inside it, please enlighten me.

//Edit: adding current code based on MBo Answer

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
   s: string;
   bm: TBitmap;
   ms ,ms1: TMemoryStream;
   len: Int64;
   JPEGImage: TJPEGImage;
begin
 IdTCPClient1.Connect;
 begin
     ms:=TMemoryStream.Create;
     ms1:=TMemoryStream.Create;
     JPEGImage := TJPEGImage.Create;

        s := 'A nice picture';
        ms:=CapScreen(100); //function result in memory stream

        len := Length(s) * SizeOf(Char);
        ms1.Write(len, SizeOf(len));
        ms1.Write(PChar(s)^, len);
        ms1.copyfrom(ms,ms.Size) ;         //    <-- stream read error
        ms1.Position := 0;
        Caption := s;
        JPEGImage.LoadFromStream(ms1);
        Image1.Picture.Assign(JPEGImage);
    end;

    IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(ms1, 0, True);
    ms.Free;
    ms1.Free;
    JPEGImage.Free;
 end;
```

Comment: If you want to include a string, and include it first, do so.

Comment: Have you tried searching this site? E.g. "[delphi] tmemorystream idtcpclient".

Comment: @TomBrunberg no because that is not my main question i know how to achieve that, i am trying to include a string in my memory stream with some sort of splitter in between so i can read both of them separately later.

Comment: If you write the length of the string, then the string and finally the picture, reading the string and picture is trivial because you know the length of the string and therefore where it ends.

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear from your post what the "main question" was. Many of the related posts that I referred to, include similar cases as your, and show you how to send what not together with whatever and more..

Comment: "*the TMemoryStream will be sent from IdTCPclient to IdTCPserver and server will read the string then the picture*" - then there is no reason to put the string inside the stream at all. Indy provides separate methods for reading/writing strings and streams. It would be far easier to just send the string first, then send the stream. Then read the string, then read the stream.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i tried to use  that, but onexecute procedure   quits out and exit! but now on fresh project i did for testing it works just fine like you said :/

Comment: @Someone "*but onexecute procedure quits out and exit!*" - Then you are not using it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example to start from. Picture is loaded from disk here

```
var
  s: string;
  bm: TBitmap;
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  len: Int64;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  bm := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bm.LoadFromFile('d:\d.bmp');
    //write string body size, body itself
    s := 'A nice picture';
    len := Length(s) * SizeOf(Char);
    ms.Write(len, SizeOf(len));
    ms.Write(PChar(s)^, len);

    //now picture
    bm.SaveToStream(ms);

    //change string and picture to be sure we load new ones
    bm.Canvas.FillRect(rect(0,0,100,100));
    s := '';

    //now restore and show
    ms.Position := 0;
    ms.Read(len, sizeof(len));
    SetLength(s, len div SizeOf(Char));
    ms.Read(PChar(s)^, len);
    Caption := s;
    bm.LoadFromStream(ms); //reads picture from current position
    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bm);
  finally
    ms.Free;
    bm.Free;
  end;
```

Example for jpeg loaded from another stream:

```
var
  s: string;
  ms, jpstream: TMemoryStream;
  len: Int64;
  jp: TJpegImage;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  jpstream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  jp := TJpegImage.Create;


  try
    //write string body size, body itself
    s := 'A nice picture';
    len := Length(s) * SizeOf(Char);
    ms.Write(len, SizeOf(len));
    ms.Write(PChar(s)^, len);

    jpstream.LoadFromFile('d:\d.jpg');
    jpstream.Position := 0;
    ms.CopyFrom(jpstream, jpstream.Size);


    //now restore ans show
    ms.Position := 0;
    ms.Read(len, sizeof(len));
    SetLength(s, len div SizeOf(Char));
    ms.Read(PChar(s)^, len);
    Caption := s;

    jp.LoadFromStream(ms);

    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, jp);
  finally
    ms.Free;
    jp.Free;
    jpstream.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: thank you but, i was able to get the string on the server side successfully but picture didn't showup! i used   |  ms1.Write(ms,SizeOf(ms)) ;    | ms is the jpeg ms1 is both str and picture 
is this wrong way to write the picture?

Comment: Completely wrong. Use `ms1.copyFrom(ms, ms.Size)`

Comment: ms1.copyFrom(ms, ms.Size)  result  stream read error

Comment: Have you reset ms.position?

Comment: yes, i will post full code in my question

Comment: i have added the code i hope you take a look

Comment: there is no `ms.Position := 0;` before copyfrom in your code

Comment: and you'll have problems later because `JPEGImage.LoadFromStream` must read from the start of jpeg rather than start of string

Comment: i did now, it still showing the same error

Comment: yeah, i know  i need to store things together then split and read each alone, my problem is how i do it in a memorystream,  i looked online for solution but it seems everyone is asking either to send a string only or a memorystream only but not both combined.. how would they know of what are they receiving from clients !!

Comment: General principle for mixed-data files and streams - write (data identificator if needed), size of data, data chunk. Repeat for all needed data. Here we don't need size of jpeg data because jpedimage load all the rest of stream, but if you need another data later, you'll have to write data size and use intermediate stream.